# MySQL not able to connect from remote client

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have my MySQL server running on machine with IP address 181.2.3.5, and I have a database called `affablebean` running on it. I am able to connect via from same machine. But when I try to access it remotely to deploy java application but I am getting below error:

> Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Access denied for user 'root'@'181.2.3.4' (using password: YES)

Both systems are on LAN. I tried below queries to grant privellages:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'sql123';
flush privileges;
```

also below thing:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to 'root'@'181.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'sql123';
flush privileges;
```

But still I am getting same error, I tried restarting mysql service but still it's not accepting connections.

Btw Server is running Windows XP and client is running on Windows 7. I also tried below query:

```
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> SELECT host FROM user WHERE user = 'root';
```

it returns my ip address correctly. But still same error. Can anyone guide me? I tried above solutions from various SO questions.

Note: Above IP address and user name are just a place holder to illustrate.

**Edit**: I am able to access from Workbench, but I am not able to access from Java program.

Comment: Uh, you connect as _root_ with a client application??

Comment: check whether your request is intercepted by any firewall.

Comment: @A.man nope, I don't have any firewall installed on my machine.

Comment: Are you passing credentials in your Java application when connecting? Could you show us the code you use to connect to the database from Java?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, yes I am passing credentials, I am using JNDI to connect to database. In MySQL I am able to see the user/host in Workbench system administration. But I am not able to access don't know why. Even I tried command line mysql, it is also giving same error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the port name with your server IP.

Like hostIP:portNumber

Answer (score 0):

Workbench and your java programs are like any other clients. So what you need to see if there are any settings difference in between these two clients, maybe wrong credentials.